# Is there a closed form for the Rudin-Shapiro sequence?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The Rudin-Shapiro sequence is defined as follows:

> Let $a_n=\sum\epsilon_i\epsilon_{i+1}$ where $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2...$ are the digits in the binary expansion of $n$. $WS(n)$, the $n$th term of the Rudin-Shapiro sequence, is defined as$$WS(n)=(-1)^{a_n}$$

My question is: Is there a closed form of this sequence? I know that it can be defined recursively as$$\begin{cases}r_{2n}&=r_n\\r_{2n+1}&=(-1)^nr_n\end{cases}$$however there doesn't seem to be a closed form of this sequence that I'm aware of, and while there does seem to be a generalized form for it ($||P||_\infty\le\sqrt2||P||_2$), I haven't been able to find a closed form.

My motivation is that I got interested in the sequence a while ago and have been trying to find a closed form of it using its recursive definition.

Comment: $$\begin{cases}r_{2n}&=r_n\\r_{2n+1}&=(-1)^nr_n\end{cases}$$ is a recursion formula for $(-1)^{t_n}$ where $(t_n)$ is the Thue-Morse sequence, not for the Rudin-Shapiro sequence.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Oh crap I must have mixed the two up let me fix that quick

Comment: OEIS does not list a closed form, I presume the answer is "no" ---https://oeis.org/A020985